# Android Kotlin - reset position after animation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I'm making a swipe animation, this is inside onCreate:

```
val distance = swipe.left.toFloat()

anim = swipe.animate().rotationBy(-30f).setDuration(1000) // SWIPE TO LEFT
    .translationX(-distance)
    .setInterpolator(AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())

anim!!.setListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {}
    override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {}
    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {}

    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
        swipe.animate().rotationBy(30f).setDuration(300)
            .translationX(distance)
            .setInterpolator(AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()).start() // RESET THE POSITION BY SWIPING BACK TO RIGHT

        Log.d("pikaboo", "wth")
    }
})

anim!!.start()
```

As you can see I try to reset it inside `onAnimationEnd` but then I get `wth` printed out multiple times per second and the swipe view disappears!

What is wrong here? How can I reset and repeat the animation?

Comment: When the animation ends another animations starts so the listener is triggered again. Try removing it or setting the listener to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `animate` on a `View`, it returns the `ViewPropertyAnimator` instance associated with that `View` - [which is a singleton](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a175a5b/core/java/android/view/View.java#14463), i.e. there's only one and you get that back each time you call `animate`

> This class is not constructed by the caller, but rather by the View whose properties it will animate. Calls to `View.animate()` will return a reference to the appropriate ViewPropertyAnimator object for that View.

So you call `animate` and save the `ViewPropertyAnimator` result as `anim`, and then set the animation listener on that. Your listener has its `onAnimationEnd` function, which starts a new animation on the same view, which means it's using the same `ViewPropertyAnimator` (`anim`), which has the listener set which starts a new animation when this one ends... see where I'm going here? You got yourself a never ending loop!

Your best bet is probably to use a one-shot end animation, which you can do with that fluent `animate` syntax anyway! No need for a listener. Try this:

```
anim = swipe.animate().rotationBy(-30f).setDuration(1000) // SWIPE TO LEFT
    .translationX(-distance)
    .setInterpolator(AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
    .withEndAction {
        swipe.animate().rotationBy(30f).setDuration(300)
            .translationX(distance)
        
       .setInterpolator(AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()).start()
    }
```

Can't fix the formatting on there (for a site about programming it's really hard to work with code in these answers) but yeah - you could clean it up by making some of it into a function anyway (since it's the same thing, just with negative values)

---

Also you should probably make `anim` a `lateinit var` instead of nullable and doing `!!` everywhere, that's a bad sign and it always causes troubles in the end!

Comment: lateint is a bad idea in this case because when the activity gets closed before anim is initialized then the necessary anim!!.cancel() inside onFinish will cause crash. Otherwise your solution works, thanks!

Comment: You could do ``if (::anim.isInitialized) anim.cancel()`` in that case - I just try and discourage people from using ``!!`` (especially for things like this, it's basically what ``lateinit`` was created for!) because it always causes problems, and it's kind of a hack to deal with the consequences of making a non-null property nullable just so you can initialise it late, y'know? I've learned this stuff the hard way :(

Comment: `withEndAction` that is a magnificent solution for plenty of use cases, gonna keep it in mind.

Comment: It's pretty sweet! Especially if you don't want to mess around with ``AnimatorSet``s. The only thing you have to watch out for is animation interruptions (like restarting the whole thing because the user tapped again)